# How to save a dictionary having value as an object

Tags: python, session, dictionary, dropbox, mongoengine

binHow to save this kind of dictionary in mongiengine.

```
{'xnFH8XCJiwMRFu8A': <dropbox.session.OAuthToken object at 0x2e4efd0>,  
 '867s6bnwbg3kc':<dropbox.session.OAuthToken object at 0x2e50610>}
```

I am trying to save the dropbox access token.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Thanks for the help.

But getting the error InvalidStringData. No idea where I am doing wrong.

code snippet is as follows:

```
  #TOKEN_STORE is the above dictionary
  dbsession = DBsession.objects.get(oauth_token=oauth_token) # oauth_token is is request

  v = pickle.dumps(TOKEN_STORE, -1)
  print v # this prints proper binary string
  print pickle.loads(v) # this prints proper values

  dbsession.update(set__token_store=v) # this line fails and throws error on  
                                       #InvalidStringData


#DBSession Definition
# me is mongoengine
class DBSession(me.Document):
    oauth_token = me.StringField(required=True)
    token_store = me.BinaryField()
```

Comment: try `pickle` or `shelve`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows exactly how to connect to mongodb and how to store stuff there.
Plz read: http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#documents

I would however not recommend using mongodb if you're using it solely for this. If you really only want to save his dict in a persistent way and you only need to access it from python you might as well use shelve http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html

Update after question has been updated:

I think it should be

```
dbsession.update(set__token_store=pickle.loads(v))
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the suggestion zhangyangyu and pypat, I used pickle.
but now getting following error:

InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8: '\x80\x02}q\x00(U\x10A2TVbIeYxoGRWDQPq\x01cdropbox.session..'

any help..

Comment: Could you please post your code? (maybe by updating your question) It looks like an encoding error but fixing it is hard without knowing what you actually did.

Comment: If I will do a pickle.loads(v), it will again convert it back to the original TOKEN_STORE dictinary and will cause error of unable to convert it to bson. That is why I am pickling it to binary value and saving it as a binary. Later when I need to access the values I will do pickle.loads(dbsession.token_store) and perform further operations. :(

Comment: I guess I'm unclear as what set__token_store expects. It doesn't expect a dict you say but I guess something from that dict otherwise you wouldn't want to pickle it :)